# Dynamic jQuery statements

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery statement:

```
 $(currentEle).parent().parent("li").next().click()
```

where `currentEle` is a `li` element.

If this part of the statement `$(currentEle).parent().parent("li").next()` returns `null`, I would like to add a `.parent().parent("li")` to the statement.

For example: `$(currentEle).parent().parent("li").parent().parent("li").next().click()` and so on. 
I have added an HTML list to make things more clear. From the list, if the currentEle is set to the li representing E, and I would like to select the next element in the list i.e. 'F'. `$(currentEle).parent().parent("li").next()`would be null and so `$(currentEle).parent().parent("li").parent().parent("li")` would do the job. So how do I make this more generic?

```
 <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B
            <ul>
                <li>C
                    <ul>
                        <li>D
                            <ul>
                                <li>E</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>F</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: if `$(currentEle).parent().parent("li").next().click()` returns `null`, then `$(currentEle).parent().parent("li").parent().parent("li")` will return null too (parent of null will be null')

Comment: @Secator. **The parent of null is exception**... not null

Comment: @gdoron not in the jQuery code in this question :)

Comment: @Olmar, I'm doing a next/previous tree traversal, the tree being constructed from an HTML list

Comment: Got it. I updated the answer after your edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Updated answer:*

I added an `id` to the E `li` to simplify the code.

**jQuery:**

```
var value = ($('#theE').parents('li').filter(function(index) {
    return $(this).next('li').length;
}).next().text());

alert(value); //F
```

**HTML:**

```
 <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B
            <ul>
                <li>C
                    <ul>
                        <li>D
                            <ul>
                                <li id="theE">E</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>F</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/E4NVb/)**

Comment: How about the reverse i.e. going back from F to E?

Comment: @AlSiddharth. It is for other question. But What is the rule?

Comment: `if ($(currentEle).prev().val() != null) {
                if ($(currentEle).prev().children("ul").length > 0) {
                    //$(currentEle).children[
                    $(currentEle).prev().children().last("li").children().last().click();
                }
                else {
                    $(currentEle).prev().click();
                }
            }`

Comment: @AlSiddharth. Please open a new thread with that new question.

Answer (score 1):

i think u mean somthing like

```
function main(){
    var curr = $(currentEle);

    while (getParent(curr) != null){
        curr = getParent(curr);
    }

    getParent(curr).next().click();
}


function getParent(element){
    if (element.parent().length > 0 && element.parent().parent('li').length > 0){
        return element.parent().parent('li');
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're really after is the [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) method, filtered by `li` to find the ancestor list item:

```
$(currentEle).parents("li").last().next().click();
```

This way you don't have to manually check each level.