# Dynamic jQuery statements Part II

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add follow-up to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9290453/601179)

```
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B
    <ul>
      <li>C
        <ul>
          <li>D
            <ul>
              <li>E</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>F</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The question concerns an HTML list navigation, previous-next to be exact. If currently F was selected, i.e., currentEle=F, how would I go to F from E. The post linked did vice-versa.
Currently I have this, but it ain't good

```
if ($(currentEle).prev().val() != null) {
  if ($(currentEle).prev().children("ul").length > 0) {                    
    $(currentEle).prev().children().last("li").children().last().click();
  }
  else {
    $(currentEle).prev().click();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code from the linked question that is necessary to understand/answer this one.

Comment: Why do you want to go from `F` to `E`? That might help understand the problem. What is the general problem here?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `this` is the node for `F`,

```
var txtToFind = 'E';
$(this).prev('li').find('li').filter(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == txtToFind)
        return true;
    else return false;
})
```

Comment: +1. with `return $(this).text() == txtToFind` will be a perfect answer.

Comment: @Thomsen: assuming that I didn't know what `txtToFind` would be, how do I go about?

Comment: This is why it would help to understand the general problem. Not just the specifics of navigating from `F` to `E`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(currentEle).prev().val() != null) {
  if ($(currentEle).prev().children("ul").length > 0) {
    $(currentEle).prev().children().last("li").children().last().click();
    var items = $(currentEle).prev().children();
    $(items).find('li').last().click();
  }
  else {
    $(currentEle).prev().click();
  }
}
```

works for me.